# Instantiate UITableViewCell For Use Outside of TableView Methods

Tags: swift, swift2

There is probably a simple answer for this.

I am trying to access variables from my custom `tableviewcell`, I have tried instantiating the cell numerous ways and each time I get an error stating that the value is nil, thus leading me to believe I have not correctly initialized the cell.

I know to instantiate a `viewcontroller` I would do something such as:

```
 let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("UserProfile") as! UserProfileViewController
```

is there a similar way to initialize a `tableviewcell`

for clarification:

I want to do something such as:

```
func doSomethign() {
   let cell = CustomTableViewCell()

   cell.user = username
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should not create cells directly in that way. Instead, you first register your cells for reuse:

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "yourNib", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CellIdentifier")
```

And then you dequeue cells when they are needed:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.user = username
    return cell
}
```

This is because the tableView will reuse cells that have scrolled off screen to improve performance. Note that it requires you set the cell's reuse identifier to match correctly.

Answer (score -2):

The correct way is that you shouldn't be doing it this way at all. As Michael pointed out, the `TableView` reuses cells, so although it is possible to get a reference to a cell, it's only possible if the cell has already been created, and hasn't thus been dequeued for reuse. In this case, what you should do is update your model, and then tell the `TableView` to reload the cell at the index corresponding to the correct model object. This way your application follows MVC design, and is more protected from crashes due to nil cell references.

Comment: Interesting how people will down-vote both of us without any comment as to why.